# Yii Relations with non-Primary keys

Tags: php, yii

I have a mysql table and a mysql view I'm trying to build relations for.

The table(`commissions`) is as follows:

```
--commissions--
id(primary Key)
date_added
order_id
salesrep_id
customer_id
commission_total
status
```

The view(`rep_view_customer`) is as follows:

```
--rep_view_customer--
entity_id
email
first_name
last_name
company
```

I'm trying to relate `rep_view_customer` to `commissions` on `commissions.customer_id = rep_view_customer.entity_id`.

I've tried using the `on` option:

```
'rep_view_customer' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'RepViewCustomer', '', 'on'=>'rep_view_customer.entity_id = t.customer_id')
```

I also tried setting the primary key for the `rep_view_customer` model using:

```
public function primaryKey(){
    return 'entity_id';
}
```

But I always seem to end up with an error similar to:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found:  1054 Unknown column 't.customer_id' in 'where
>   clause'.  The SQL statement executed was: SELECT
>   `rep_view_customer`.`entity_id` AS `t1_c0`,
>   `rep_view_customer`.`email` AS `t1_c1`,
>   `rep_view_customer`.`first_name` AS `t1_c2`,
>   `rep_view_customer`.`last_name` AS `t1_c3`,
>   `rep_view_customer`.`company` AS `t1_c4` FROM `rep_view_customer`
>   `rep_view_customer` WHERE (rep_view_customer.entity_id =
>   t.customer_id)

I'm at my wit's end what to try next

Comment: could you please elaborate code on the controller function that 'calls' the rep_view_customer? because it seems from the CdbCommand debugger there are no joins happening

Comment: @ZaQ `it seems from the CdbCommand debugger there are no joins happening` i was a getting confused at that as well. I was using the default Admin CGridView created by Gii and added a column 'rep_view_customer.first_name'. I only get the error if i add the related column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a foreign key inside repview_customer to relate to commissions. You won't be able to do it with just a primary key.

Comment: I've tried that but i only get errors. I did some digging on the errors, made sure i had the right datatype for both columns, but from what i found, mysql does not allow foreign keys in views.

Comment: post the error, your errors might be because the data isn't of same type.

Comment: The data are both the same type INT(10) UNSIGNED. I used the following mysql `ALTER TABLE customer ADD  CONSTRAINT customer_id FOREIGN    KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES rep_view_customer(entity_id)` and get the error `#1005 - Can't create table 'salesrep_1.#sql-da8_9c4' (errno: 150)`.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way and it works:
so in the commissions model you put: (it does the relation through itself within the model, then the join output will be the same as the normal relation but with other unique key in commission model)

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'commission' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Commission', 'entity_id', 'on' => 'commission.customer_id=rep_view_customer.entity_id'),
            'rep_view_customer' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'RepViewCustomer', '', 'through' => 'commission', 'condition' => '...'),
        ),
    }
```